# How to use config data in nested forRoot modules

Tags: angular

I used a core module in my project for multiple apps. Every app should have a different api url. The core module imports include a lot of externals libs and many of them requires configuration object to get them imported. For example, [ngx-jsonapi](https://github.com/reyesoft/ngx-jsonapi) required a base api url, so, how can I change the api url for every app through my core module config object into the externals modules.

There's 2 point that not shown in my example (to make the question simple as possible) but really necessary to knowing:

- I’m using config service to inject the config object in many places of the core module (mainly in the core's services).
- The config object loaded from JSON file to get the option to change the configuration in production.

**One of the apps main module:**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CoreModule} from '@app-common/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CoreModule.forRoot({
      url: 'API-URL' <= Api url should to pass here.
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**And here is the common core module:**

```
import {NgxJsonapiModule} from 'ngx-jsonapi';
import {throwIfAlreadyLoaded} from '@app-common/core/module-import-guards';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxJsonapiModule.forRoot({
      url: 'API-URL' <= Api url should used from the config object that pass into the forRoot method of the core module.
    })
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {
  static forRoot(config: {url: string}): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ProteanCoreModule,
      providers: []
    };
  }
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule, router: Router) {
    throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, 'CoreModule');
  }
}
```